# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException Response code 500. Message: session not created:

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdrivermanager-java, cft

I am getting the below error in my Java selenium project

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.97 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

I have upgraded the selenium dependency to `4.11.0` and webdrivermanager version - `5.5.2` and my browser version is `116.0.5845.97`. But still getting the error. I could see some changes happened in the chrome link `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application` yesterday and after that I am facing this issue.(Please refer the attached image). In my company, it's restricted to CFT endpoint download.  Is there any workarounds to sort this error.

Comment: you are using webdrivermanager or seleniummanager to launching your application. if Yes?, then there is bug and was raised, you can also it in GitHub. but if you are not using these library for launching the methods, and then share your code here.